# If turtle on red patch change color to red

Tags: netlogo

I would like to make it so that my turtle changes color depending on the patch it is touching. So, if it touches a red patch, it turns red, or if to touches a green patch, it turns green.

This is how I have my patches setup:

```
*to setup-patches
   ask patches [set pcolor white]
   ask patches with [pycor = 16][set pcolor red]
   ask patches with [pycor = -16][set pcolor green]
  ask patches with [pxcor = 16][set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor = -16][set pcolor yellow]
end *
```

I've tried using the cone shape to detect the color, but when changing the set heading to set the color of the turtle, it doesn't work. What is a solution or a different method for doing this?

```
 `
*let front-patches patches in-cone 2 75
  if ([pcolor]) of one-of front-patches = red ([set heading heading - 90])*`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you want to use `in-cone`. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "touching". If you simply mean the patch the turtle is currently on, this is rather easy.

```
ask turtles [set color [pcolor] of patch-here]
```

You wouldn't have to include the `of patch-here` since turtles can read and set patch variables of the patch they are standing on.

```
ask turtles [set color pcolor]
```